# Need help in sending javascript hash to rails action through ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

This is my JS function,

function checkHash()
{

```
var myHash = {"apples": 3, "oranges": 4, "bananas": 42}

var url = '../../some_contoller/some_action'
var pars = 'myHash=' + encodeURIComponent(myHash)


var myAjax = new Ajax.Request(
  url,
    {
      method: 'get',
      asynchronous: asyncFlag,
      parameters: pars,
      onSuccess: function(transport) {

        //alert(transport.responseText);
        try {
          tax_hash = eval('('+transport.responseText+')');
          //alert("tax_hash = " + tax_hash)
        }
        catch(err){
          return

        }    
     onFailure: function() {
     }
```

}
 }
       )
 }

Rails action,

def some_action

```
p params    ##It will print {"myHash"=>"[object Object]"}
```

end

I want to print {"apples": 3, "oranges": 4, "bananas": 42}

Comment: `var pars = 'myHash=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(myHash))` ...?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.I tried your answer, now it is printing {"myHash"=>{}}.

Comment: Do this (see, there should't be 'myHash=' literal):  
 
[code]var pars = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(myHash))[/code]

Answer (score 0):

First off, it's not a good idea to use eval on the results of your AJAX request.  It's much better to have the request be interpreted as JSON (if that's all you're using it for).

Here is info on how to tell rails to return JSON: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-json

Also I would recommend only returning the params you're interested in and not all of them:

```
def some_action
    render json: params.reject {|k,v| ![:action,:controller, :other_params].include?(k)}
end
```